# I want the applescript to select text field 2 of sheet 1 of window "App Store" of application process "App Store",but it does not work, why?

Tags: macos, applescript

I want  the applescript  to  select text field 2 of sheet 1 of window "App Store" of application process "App Store"   ,but it does not work, why? what is wrong? please help me. thank you!
When the   Apple ID is already exists,  I want  to select  text field 2 (text field  of Apple ID),  and then clear the old  app id , keystroke  "  another app id" 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi78V.png)

This  is  my   applescript :

```
tell application "App Store" to activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            click menu item 12 of menu 1 of menu bar item 4 of menu bar 1 of application process "App Store"
        end try
    end tell
    delay 1

    tell application "System Events"
        delay 2
        select text field 2 of sheet 1 of window "App Store" of application process "App Store"
        key code 51 using {command down, shift down}
        keystroke " another app id"
        keystroke tab
        keystroke "password"
        key code 36
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to select it first. It works for me to set the value of the field.
But on my machine right now, the password field index is 1, not 2 (osx 10.10.5 here). The login field is index 2.

I can do the following to set field 2 to whatever I want, as long as the following is within a tell block for "App Store" which is within the tell block for "System Events":

```
set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of window "App Store" to someValue
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience to help me solve this troubled me for a long time

Answer (score 1):

You were really close with your initial script. These changes should work for you.

```
tell application "App Store" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    try
        click menu item 12 of menu 1 of menu bar item 4 of menu bar 1 of application process "App Store"
    end try
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    delay 2
    set value of text field 2 of sheet 1 of window "App Store" of application process "App Store" to "enter_the_account_you_want_to_use" -- put the account name in between those quotes
    keystroke tab
    keystroke "password"
    delay 1
    key code 36
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience to help me solve this troubled me for a long time